# Gmail & Google Apps Script: Find out the date a label is applied

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

In Google Apps Script, is there a way to find out the date (timestamp) a label is applied to an email conversation in Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this unless you nonitor changes by polling which isnt practical unless its for a small set of conversations.

Comment: It's a small sample (basically only emails in the inbox). How would I poll for changes? For example, by creating an hourly project trigger and comparing both conversations states (before trigger, after trigger)?

Comment: Yes thats the way but om typing more so s.o. lets me enter the comment

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your last comment completely.

Comment: Take the first 4 words. Rest was because s.o. wouldnt comment only 4 words.